# Why do I get the same PAPR effect with all modulation orders in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, ofdm

I am using the basic way to calculate the PAPR of OFDM system using MATLAB, the strange thing I noticed that I get almost the same PAPR effect even when increasing the modulation order from 4 to 64. I couldn't explain the cause of that issue. Here is the code I use:

```
N = 256; 
M = 4; 

PAPR_ofdm = zeros(1, 10^5);  %initialize 
for J = 1 : 10^5 
    J
      bi = randi([0 M-1], N, 1);  %generate data 
      xi = qammod(bi, M , 'UnitAveragePower', true);  %Modulation 
      Xi_t = ifft(xi); 
      PAPR_ofdm(J) = 10*log10(max(abs(Xi_t.^2)) ./ mean(abs(Xi_t.^2)));
end 

[cdf_ofdm, PAPR_ofdm] = ecdf(PAPR_ofdm);           % PAPR 

figure(1);
semilogy(PAPR_ofdm, 1-cdf_ofdm, 'b:','LineWidth',2.0);hold on   % 
grid on
legend('Conventional OFDM');
```

Here is the result I get with M = 4 and M = 64:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the distribution for OFDM waveforms after the IFFT, prior to using additional crest factor reduction techniques, closely approach a Gaussian, regardless of modulation order. Therefore the PAPR will be very similar for all case. Assuming random data assignment to each subcarrier, the IFFT is a sum of independent and identically distributed random variables, which approaches a Gaussian as the FFT size grows consistent with the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)].  If we had independent subcarriers that were each Gaussian noise (or any distribution) or simple binomial distributions (BPSK), the result would still approach a Gaussian distribution (as long as each are independent with similar standard deviations).

Here are plots from my own OFDM simulations shown PAPR versus modulation order for different FFT sizes. Notice that only in the case of the very small FFT size can you distinguish PAPR versus modulation order of the sub-carriers. Otherwise it is all consistent with the Central Limit Theorem (Gaussian), as expected. I included a simulation with Gaussian noise to show how that compares to the OFDM result.

[image: FFT 1024]

[image: FFT 512]

[image: FFT 128]

[image: FFT 32]

[image: FFT 16]

Comment: Yes, but ideally increasing the modulation order should increase the level of PAPR, is that right?  I mean when I increase M from 4 to 64, I supposed to get higher PAPR not the same.

Comment: @Fatima_Ali No, increasing the modulation order does not increase the level of PAPR. It will be the same, for larger FFT sizes it all approaches a Gaussian. I will add some of my own plots.

Comment: @Fatima_Ali the Normal distribution of `Xi_t` (by the CLT) is unchanged regardless of modulation order `M` because you have normalized the constellations by `xi = qammod(bi, M , 'UnitAveragePower', true);`

Comment: @AlexTP Even when I used `xi = qammod(bi, M)` , I get the same results. Or, you mean using another way to avoid the normalized constellation?

Comment: @DanBoschen OK, thank you, I got it. However, what I was thinking before that the PAPR is upper bounded the the absolute summation square of N modulated data divided by the mean square , so when using higher `M`, the absolute value will be higher.

Comment: @Fatima_Ali What I said is wrong as both the mean and the largest order statistic are scaled by the same factor. However, the essence is still correct: just write down the distribution of `Xi_t` you will see that the distributions are just the same Normal up to a scaling factor that depends on the average energy of your constellation. Also, sorry @DanBoschen for hijacking their answer LOL.

Comment: @DanBoschen Yap, thank you. However I still have some confusion of that PAPR and will lower PAPR save the power ? I will come back and ask another question separatly.

Comment: Sounds good- read through this post as it may answer your question regarding power amplifier linearity and power dissipation: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41130/envelope-behavior-difference-between-qpsk-oqpsk-and-pi-4-qpsk/41133#41133

Answer (score 0):

**1.- Fatima is right: Increasing QAM order INCREASES PAPR, for a single QAM carrier**

```
close all;clear all;clc

M = [2 4 16 64 256];       % qam modulation index

N = 256;   % length input signal
```

With a long enough time sequence there's no need to repeat `J` times or even calculate **IFFT**, to get `PAPR`

```
% for k = 1 :1 : J
 
T=zeros(1,4);

for k=1:1:numel(M)
        
    x = randi([0 M(k)-1], N, 1);      % generate data 

    [ai,aq]= qmmod(x, M(k));         % qmmod produces W-gam [ai aq] pairs
      
    Px_avg =  mean(ai.^2+aq.^2);    
    Px_peak = max(ai.^2+aq.^2);    
    PAPR=Px_peak/Px_avg;

    Px_avg_dB=10*log10(Px_avg);
    Px_peak_dB=10*log10(Px_peak);
    PAPR_dB=10*log10(PAPR);

    T=[T ; M(k) Px_avg_dB Px_peak_dB PAPR_dB];

end
T(1,:)=[];

T
```

Fatima is right, with `N` increasing, `N` being the QAM order or index, then `PAPR_dB` the first column from the right hand side, also increases.

```
T =
    2.0000         0         0         0
    4.0000   11.3731   12.5527    1.1796
   16.0000   17.5468   19.9123    2.3654
   64.0000   20.3468   23.8382    3.4914
  256.0000   22.2019   26.5321    4.3302
```

Ignore the 1st line of `T`, `qmmod.m` is a work in progress.

Note I use `qmmod` instead of the Communications Toolbox `qammod` because
I am working on a **QAM** modulation function that includes as input the actual signal power, any power level, this feature not shown in the following **qmmod.m**

```
function [ai aq]=qmmod(x,M)   % ,P)
% QAM generation of I and Q values on constellation
% M : QAM index 
% 1st release : Only square constellations : M can only be one of these [2 4 16 64 256]
%
% P : signal power, by default QAM is built 
% M=2 : [-1 1] 
% M=4 : [-1 1] x [-1 -1] 
% M=8 : [-3 -1 1 3] x [-3 -1 1 3]
% ..
% P[W] adjusting signal amplitudes to match P
%
% next version: M range [2 4 12 16 28 32 60 64 124 128 252 256]
% next version: custom assignment of constellation points, suggesting best fit

log2M=log2(M);
A=1;
x=A*x(:);

s=0;   % switch case, 0 not assigned

% set s and tc
if M==2 s=1; end  % no Q
if M>2 s=2; end 

ai=zeros(numel(x),1);
aq=zeros(numel(x),1);

switch s
    case 1   % M=2; [-1 1]; Q null
        ai=2*x-1;
        
    case 2   % M>2

        x2=x+1;
        [I Q]=meshgrid(-(2*log2M-1):2:(2*log2M-1));
        Q=flip(Q);
      
        for k=1:1:numel(x2)
            ai(k)=I(x2(k));
            aq(k)=Q(x2(k));
        end
             
    otherwise
        
end
    
% power adjustment: working on it

end
```

**2.- X2(f)=ifft(x) and x(t) are basically the same signal, so X2 and x have same power**

As shown in `T`, increasing `N` increases `PAPR`,

**but this is for 1 isolated QAM carrier.**

`ifft` is used to keep many QAM carriers very close in frequency without
interfering one other, avoiding  **spectral regrowth** typical of analog TV PAL Secam NSTC AM FM SSB analog modulations need consistent empty spectrum between **adjacent channels** that render them not efficient in comparison to OFDM based wireless systems.

Even ADSL uses **OFDM** to cover the last mile in analog telephony, now being replaced with Fiber-to-home, gradually.

`X2=ifft(x)` so both `x` and `X2` have the same power because both `X2` and `x` are the same signal.

**3.- Dan is also right, OFDM keeps PAPR almost constant**

**OFDM** based signals are superior to single carriers because a lot more **data/Hz** can be sent/received.

With much higher data rates, besides more raw larger payload, more sophisticated coding is possible.

**4.- Input signal stats alone may force single QAM carrier power and PAPR to change, even abruptly**

This

[image]

is, in general terms, a single **QAM** carrier.

The same way that one cab driver most of time doesn't have, and doesn't want to have a clue who is going to be the next customer, but the public transport of a city can and do model quite accurately traffic volumes, for a single we can shape g but a b are unknown.

However when having 2000/8000 **QAM** carriers (DVB-T) nicely interleaved using **IFFT** then stats of `a` and `b` can be shaped.

Using a single carrier `a` `b`

- Perhaps **are going to push outer symbols to carry most of the
  'weight'** thus increasing the mean power of this carrier and reducing
  `PPAR`.
- OR `a` `b` **show really low mean values**, reaching seldom reaching
  to the outer constellation, causing high `PAPR`.

**OFDM** 'randomizes' the input stream with coding that adds enough bytes to shift mean values of `a` `b` to keep `PPAR` steady.

**5.-English alphabet stats alone hardly apply to internet traffic statistics**

Don't get me wrong, English is The lingua franca, but bare English text, or for the matter any human language text, all together are a tiny percentage of the internet traffic therefore their stats hardly shape telecommunications stats. Internet is machine-to-machine traffic, and trending.

The following histogram may be considered a **really basic probability distribution of the A-Z alphabet for the English language**

[image]

at least according to 'Cryptological Mathematics' author : Robert E. Lewand, 2000.

Don't have the book so I captured values directly on the publicly  available graph

```
A=imread('002.jpg');
A2=A(:,:,1);
A3=~imbinarize(A2);
figure; 
ax=gca
imshow(A3);

sprintf('click on X axis')
[x_x_axis,y_x_axis]=ginput(1);  % y_x_axis is p=0

sprintf('click on top graph frame p=0.08')  % p=.08
[x08,y08]=ginput(1)

sprintf('now click once on top of each bar')
[xabc,yabc]=ginput(26);

P=(y_x_axis-yabc)/(y_x_axis-y08)*.08-.011717171717172/26

sum(P)
```

[image]

[image]

`P` neither include numbers, nor capital characters, or any punctuation, .. not really useful, is it?

Let alone the contents of HTML CSS JS files sent over exceeds
bare language texts. And then volumes of imagery traded over the internet are simply put staggering in comparison.

**The only way to control** `a` **and** `b` **is through coding**; not once modulated, and least of all attempting **Automatic Gain Control**
once in band, that AGC are used, but the signal on transmitting antenna has to be as stable as possible, In a way to speak : **Once in production everything tends to roll downhill pretty fast**.

Often such coding is proprietary, or it takes time to get to it, and understand it: always that missing function, or not publicly updated, ..

**Compression** and **encryption** help disguise the actual statistics of source files.

**Controlling power levels allows accurate coverage calculations.**

As soon big mobile communications understood the advantages of **OFDM** over single carrier systems they all decided to upgrade, at double.

**6.- Concise OFDM simulation, in MATLAB**

I just found a really nice and concise **OFDM** simulation script, in MATLAB that may be of help in this question.

**OFDM Simulation Using MATLAB**
Author : G. Acosta, August, 2000, at the Smart Antenna Research Laboratory at what I guess is the University of Chicago
Faculty Advisor: PhD M. A. Ingram

Highly recommended to Fatima, if developing OFDM simulation in MATLAB, to read the published text [available here](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.gatech.edu/dist/c/488/files/2016/09/Tutorial_web.pdf)

The following lines are just a part, just transmission

```
%DVB-T 2K Transmission
%The available bandwidth is 8 MHz
%2K is intended for mobile services

close all;clear all;clc

%DVB-T Parameters
Tu=224e-6; %useful OFDM symbol period
T=Tu/2048; %baseband elementary period
G=0; %choice of 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, and 1/32
delta=G*Tu; %guard band duration
Ts=delta+Tu; %total OFDM symbol period
Kmax=1705; %number of subcarriers
Kmin=0;
FS=4096; %IFFT/FFT length
q=10; %carrier period to elementary period ratio
fc=q*1/T; %carrier frequency
Rs=4*fc; %simulation period
t=0:1/Rs:Tu;
%Data generator (A)
M=Kmax+1;
rand('state',0);
a=-1+2*round(rand(M,1)).'+i*(-1+2*round(rand(M,1))).';
A=length(a);
info=zeros(FS,1);
info(1:(A/2)) = [ a(1:(A/2)).']; %Zero padding
info((FS-((A/2)-1)):FS) = [ a(((A/2)+1):A).'];
%Subcarriers generation (B)
carriers=FS.*ifft(info,FS);
tt=0:T/2:Tu;
figure(1);
subplot(211);
stem(tt(1:20),real(carriers(1:20)));

subplot(212);
stem(tt(1:20),imag(carriers(1:20)));
figure(2);
f=(2/T)*(1:(FS))/(FS);
subplot(211);
plot(f,abs(fft(carriers,FS))/FS);
subplot(212);
pwelch(carriers,[],[],[],2/T);
% D/A simulation
L = length(carriers);
chips = [ carriers.';zeros((2*q)-1,L)];
p=1/Rs:1/Rs:T/2;
g=ones(length(p),1); %pulse shape
figure(3);
stem(p,g);
dummy=conv(g,chips(:));
u=[dummy(1:length(t))]; % (C)
figure(4);
subplot(211);
plot(t(1:400),real(u(1:400)));
subplot(212);
plot(t(1:400),imag(u(1:400)));
figure(5);
ff=(Rs)*(1:(q*FS))/(q*FS);
subplot(211);
plot(ff,abs(fft(u,q*FS))/FS);
subplot(212);
pwelch(u,[],[],[],Rs);
[b,a] = butter(13,1/20); %reconstruction filter
[H,F] = freqz(b,a,FS,Rs);
figure(6);
plot(F,20*log10(abs(H)));
uoft = filter(b,a,u); %baseband signal (D)
figure(7);
subplot(211);
plot(t(80:480),real(uoft(80:480)));
subplot(212);
plot(t(80:480),imag(uoft(80:480)));
figure(8);
subplot(211);
plot(ff,abs(fft(uoft,q*FS))/FS);
subplot(212);
pwelch(uoft,[],[],[],Rs);

%Upconverter
s_tilde=(uoft.').*exp(1i*2*pi*fc*t);
s=real(s_tilde); %passband signal (E)
figure(9);
plot(t(80:480),s(80:480));
figure(10);
subplot(211);

%plot(ff,abs(fft(((real(uoft).').*cos(2*pi*fc*t)),q*FS))/FS);
%plot(ff,abs(fft(((imag(uoft).').*sin(2*pi*fc*t)),q*FS))/FS);
plot(ff,abs(fft(s,q*FS))/FS);
subplot(212);
%pwelch(((real(uoft).').*cos(2*pi*fc*t)),[],[],[],Rs);
%pwelch(((imag(uoft).').*sin(2*pi*fc*t)),[],[],[],Rs);
pwelch(s,[],[],[],Rs);
```

[image]

This script allows now to go for **OFDM signal power calculations measuring in-channel power directly on the spectrum of the signal**, which is how in general all operators do it because it's what the operator essentially pays for:

**On-Air Signal power reaching subscribers**.

If you now **play with the the input signal**, you can directly simulate `mean` and `peak` **OFDM power**, not on just a single QAM carrier, that as explained above relies heavily on the statistical nature of the input signal, while the **Coding behind OFDM && OFDM many carriers** both hand-in-hand, *harden* the system against any incoming statistical behaviour.

In my opinion this is a good start point to achieving reliable **OFDM** `PAPR` and `CCDF` simulations.

Note that mobile comms operators use variations and upgrades of the **OFDM** DVB-T system here explained: Mobile comms operators removed a lot of armour to maximise payload, tower-mobile distances are most of times far shorter than broadcast antenna to roof antenna. And because cells hugely vary, mobile comms signal levels are also far more disperse, even on base station antenna and indeed down to the hard-working subscription payers.

Comment: Thank you for the details you provided, but I have some points couldn't get them, 1- In your first point, you are using `qmmod` to produce the constellation without normalization, but I see the output is little bit strange. for example when using `[a b] = qmmod(bi,4);` which is equivalent to `M = 4`; I real part  `a` all equal to -3 and `b` is a logic mapping signal. in that case `T` is logic as you are increasing he amplitude of `a`   2- Is the output of the function you use equivalent to `qammod(x, M(k))` ?, I mean the same function of MATLAB toolbox but without normalizing the power.

Comment: If so, the OFDM PAPR also will be the same for all levels of `M` according to the results of MATLAB.   In your point 2, you mentioned that X2 and x(t) are the same, what you mean by x(t), is it x? I agree they have the same average power as the Fourier matrix is unitary, but I think they are different in ofdm as X2 might include the summation of all signals x inserted to different subcarriers, right?  Finally, what do you mean by single QAM carrier? Is it single carrier modulation?

Comment: To Fatima, I have posted a 2nd answer that complements the 1st one answering the questions you have asked as comments, questions that are closely related to the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

**ADDITIONAL COMMENTS**

Hi Fatima, the following comments answer the additional questions closely related to this post question :

**1.-**
*In your first point, you are using qmmod to produce the constellation without normalization, but I see the output is little bit strange. for example when using `[a b] = qmmod(bi,4);` which is equivalent to `M = 4;` I real part a all equal to -3 and b is a logic mapping signal. in that case `T` is logic as you are increasing he amplitude of `a`*

`T` is just a table showing results: `T` left column is M : the **QAM** index or order.

`T` furthest right column is PAPR in dB : `PAPR_dB`

**If you hold same signal power constant while putting more constellation points**, the BER is going to suffer, **BER goes up**, the quality of the signal then goes down, and the bitrate goes down.

Bitrate is what all operators need as high as possible to maximise revenue.

When smartphones start losing traffic, apps stop working, customers drop subscriptions. No money : bad.

High bit rates : money up, good.

To compare the **PAPR** of **2 carriers**, one against the other, whatever carriers, 2 single QAM carriers, 2 OFDM carriers .. my understanding is that **the bitrate has to be the same**.

Let's say smartphones using 100Mbps all ok with PAPR=10dB.

The operator thinks : To keep those 100Mbps **do I really need to pay for a 15W base station?** or can I reduce it to 10W **WHILE HOLDING BITRATE** meaning the average power has to be there, doing the work of supplying enough **Eb/N0** to keep **BER low enough**.

Does the operator really need peak power to go much higher than average power?

This means, can the operator reduce **PAPR** thus saving a lot across thousands of base stations lowering peak powers **WHILE KEEPING** same **Quality of Service**?

**The sought PAPR reduction is to lower peaks.**.

The **PAPR** analysis should include **BER(Eb/N0)** checks, to make sure that **BER** remains constant, when increasing/decreasing `M` the **QAM** modulation index.

It's not just increase `M` and see what happens, but the other way round, with `M` decreasing does the operator still make lots of money?

Solely to such purpose : **does BER remain where I have it satisfying customers?**

The purpose of comparing is that for same quality = same error probability = keep constant spacing between adjacent constellation points, then how does PAPR behave. And the point you don't mention, does BER hold?

**2.1.-** *Is the output of the function you use equivalent to `qammod(x, M(k))` ?, I mean the same function of MATLAB toolbox but without normalizing the power*

**2.2.-** *If so, the OFDM PAPR also will be the same for all levels of M according to the results of MATLAB.*

Don't think so, **no** to both 2.1 and 2.2.

Answering **2.1** : You use `qammod` with the option

`qammod(bi,M,'UnitAveragePower',true)`

This means that with `M` increasing (adding points in **QAM** constellation) you force `qammod` to constrain more points within same constellation square.

This also means closer constellation points, that causes **BER** go up, **QoS** down: bad. You have to keep **QoS** as **high** and as **CONSTANT** as possible **BOTH AT THE SAME TIME**.

**Below certain signal power BER is no longer constant, you don't want that, AVERAGE Power levels have to remain above certain thresholds, or you start losing money.**

**This means constellation points cannot come too close : but this is what you do with `qammod` option setting modulation power to the only power value that `qammod` can constrain to : 1W.**

Try command `genqammod` general **QAM** modulation.

I haven't tried, not going to. Perhaps `genqammod` can set different power levels **SO THAT** `Eb/N0` and `BER` remain constant.

Even with not so good **QoS**, if you as operator guarantee 95% time year **QoS** of 95% mobiles above and acceptable threshold, your customers will remain  with you, and more customers will subscribe because you have a stable network, an network that has to be as invisible as possible to your customers on all sides of the network.

If for instance the **QoS** you offer is wonderful on weekends but during the week smartphones cannot check emails because of dropped packets and while watching real time videos and listening real time audio, such streams start buffering, that's a no-really-no way, a don't-go-there situation.

To **2.2** : You have asked for **OFDM PAPR** but you still have not generated an **OFDM** signal. The code you supplied in your question generates many many times 1 and only 1 QAM carrier.

Yes from the signal power point of view some literture shows with maths that because **OFDM** carriers are not correlated, with `K` carriers then the **OFDM** signal has `K` times the power of a single carrier.

But although `P_OFDM` is approximately `K*P_QAM`, the carriers are sharing data from the same stream, that is coded, encrypted, and is made as mean flat as possible, **BUT** they do share the same `a` and `b`, the `a+1j*b` **QAM** envelope that I call `ai` `aq` .

**If you jam 1/5th of all QAM carriers inside an OFDM carrier, **completely, bang, SNR flat on 1/5th of the OFDM channel** the BER doesn't go up, there's no data loss, not at all. This is because data is somehow repeated across the QAM carriers within 1 OFDM carrier.**

IF you want to measure **OFDM** signals, generate **OFDM** signals.

If you want to simulate **OFDM** signals, build **OFDM** signals.

This is what I answered to your question supplying working MATLAB code written by Costas, a good start point to simulate **DVB-T OFDM** signals.

I know, **DVB-T** is no longer the fashion **OFDM** on stage, now it's about mobile comms, but it's the one I know best.

I am sure that with a bit of research you can find **3G 4G 5G OFDM** simulations in MATLAB, or any other coding language, that build signals that in turn allow you to measure signal avg power, peak power, `PAPR`, `Eb/N0`, `BER`.

**OFDM** used in mobile comms **OFDM** have many signalling channels that are not needed in **DVB-T**.

**DVB-T** is a on-way motor way for data. Tower-to-customer, although there are **DVB** variations that have return channels, in real time, not necessarily through same network. Nowadays there's a lot more money and work in mobile comms thank in broadcast.

Mobile comms also use shorter radio links and the towers provide 'soft' hand-shakes that have evolved to mobile phones pulling/pushing data from multiple towers around them. Towers generate beans that focus energy and mobile phones use multiple towers to precisely **keep (QoS high && constant) as possible** = **Keep BER as (low && constant) as possible.**

When I briefly installed some NB for 3G, one of the tasks closing installations was either leave a `BER` meter plugged to the indoor base station equipment, left overnight, to collect and validate `BER` ok. Or some base stations wouldn't need `BER` meter, but they were left 'data looped back' in the configuration menu, feeding back all data received, back to a **service SIM** card that would be driven around while recording and checking `BER` stable across some points considered very good or very bad within that cell, from the **BER** point of view.

**3.1.-** *In your point 2, you mentioned that `X2` and `x(t)` are the same, what you mean by `x(t)`, is it `x`?*

Yes `x(t)` is `x` . `x(t)` is not actually MATLAB code, that it can be, but not here.

You use `xi` and `Xi_t` . I considered `xi` to be confusing because I use `ai` for **In-phase** and `aq` for **Quadrature** so I put a `2` next to capital `X` for the result of **FFT** transforms.

**FFT** and **IFFT** are not that different; yes **FFT** goes from time to frequency and **IFFT** from `f` to `t`.

But to a computer or program, computationally speaking, these 2 operations are not that different.

Mind the gap, the `1/N` factor may change when changing amounts of time samples and amounts of frequencies.

**3.2.-** *I agree they have the same average power as the Fourier matrix is unitary, but I think they are different in ofdm as X2 might include the summation of all signals x inserted to different subcarriers, right?*

In your code, at least in the question, the way you use `ifft` **does not produce an OFDM signal**, it produces an **FFT** of a single **QAM** carrier.

You are actually doing **IFFT** not **FFT**, but I deliberately say **FFT** so you understand that **IFFT itself only generates OFDM when you do**

`ifft(sum([x1 x2 x3 .. x998 x999 x1000]))`

small *x-ith* being the individual QAM carriers `x1(t)` `x2(t)` `x3(t)` ... `x1000(t)` necessary to **build 1 OFDM carrier** .

Each `xi(t)` has a different frequency, and although mathematically orthogonal, and thus we can put them very close one another, in reality their spectral presence affects nearby carriers. Noise is always there. Even the outer space that everybody says it's completely empty, it has 2.7 Kelvin noise temperature.

The simulated **OFDM** signal that I show closing my answer, the brick of 2000 carriers, the real signals usually have between **SNR 20dB and 25dB peak-to-shoulder** as per requirements of operators. SNR measurement peak-to-shoulder is done on lowest and highest carriers, to ground noise level. In DVB-T those 2 'edge' carriers are pilots that do not carry payload data.

The simulation shows `SNR` 80dB peak-to-shoulder that never happens in reality.

This is only a simulation: Without **amplitude noise**, without **phase noise**, without 200 **phones nearby**, and 15 **nearby towers** producing similar signals.

**4.-** *Finally, what do you mean by single QAM carrier? Is it single carrier modulation?*

`qammod` and `qmmod` generate 1 **QAM** carrier, **only one**.

Your code generates just 1 **QAM** carrier.

I start with a single carrier, to explain something, to then generate 1 **OFDM** carrier, a signal that comprises many carriers on different frequencies sharing coded data.

**The MATLAB lines supplied in your question does not generate an OFDM signal.**

**5.-** *OFDM is a group of many carriers, quite close each other, but with frequencies and power levels such there's little or no interference throughout the channel or against adjacent channels. OFDM carriers can be configured to be all N-QAM but depending upon the standard other modulations different than QAM can be used.
QAM is among the most efficient single-carrier modulations from the data_rate/Hz = bps/Hz bps: bits/second. This is why often is the preferred choice, but not always.*

Correct again.

There's a lot of interference, doppler, ..

So

```
ifft((ai1+1j*b1)*g*exp(1j*w1*t))
```

is not the same as

```
ifft((ai1+1j*b1)*g*exp(1j*w1*t) + (ai2+1j*b2)*g*exp(1j*w2*t) + ...
      (ai1+1j*b1)*g*exp(1j*w3*t) + (ai2+1j*b1)*g*exp(1j*w4*t) + ...
    ...
      (ai7997+1j*b7997)*g*exp(1j*w7997*t) + (ai7998+1j*b7998)*g*exp(1j*w7998*t) + ...
      (ai7999+1j*b7999)*g*exp(1j*w7999*t) + (ai8000+1j*b8000)*g*exp(1j*w8000*t) + ...)
```

add just a little bit of noise and you will see the difference.

Wireless channels sometimes are really really noisy to the point of completely jamming some of **QAM** carriers building 1 **OFDM** carrier.

**OFDM** coding (kind-of) repeats coded data across carriers so there's no actual loss of data in the event of partial channel interference, thus not causing 'send again' requests.

**Keep BER low && stable**.

I hope this explanation helps, all the best, thanks for your attention.`